# Не добавляется способ входа

Tags: дефект, способы-входа

Хочу добавить новый способ входа *(по почте и паролю, на данный момент вхожу через GitHub)*
[image: Добавление способов входа]
Заполняю поля, появляется окно об отправке ссылки для подтверждения на email.

> A confirmation link has been sent to ******@mail.ru
>
> Open the link in this browser to finish adding your new log in.

Захожу на почту, перехожу по ссылке для подтверждения нового способа входа и появляется сообщение об ошибке
[image: Ошибка]

Пишу на мету по причине того, что такое явление наблюдается с 8 ноября.

UPD. По подсказкам из комментариев попробовал добавить способ по логину/паролю через англоязычный SO, всё получилось. Однако вопрос открыт, т.к. непонятно почему данный способ не добавлялся на ruSO.

Comment: Попробуйте то же самое провернуть на англоязычном сайте, если повторится - имеет смысл сразу писать на MSE.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ на англоязычном всё как нужно отработало

Comment: В таком случае исправления скорее всего придётся ждать на порядок дольше. Сочувствую. А вообще, разве после подключения входа через Email на англоязычном сайте, он не распространится одновременно на ruSO?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, но у SE аккаунт общий. Если ты добавил способ входа на другом сайте, то я бы ожидал, что он и тут работает. Можешь проверить?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да, распространяется. на SO добавил способ входа, теперь через почту/пароль удачно логинится и на SO и на ruSO. однако всё-таки вопрос считаю открытым, т.к. не понятно почему данный функционал не работал на ruSO.

Comment: @Qwertiy отписал выше комментарий. непонятно почему на ruSO он не добавлялся.

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, не работал потому что нельзя добавить то, что уже добавлено.

Comment: @Qwertiy так он не работал ДО ТОГО как на SO добавился.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я понял, что он уже добавил на английском, а потом у него не вышло повторить на русском?

Comment: @Qwertiy я понял иначе, исходя из первых комментариев под вопросом, но лучше, конечно, чтобы ТС сам уточнил.

Comment: @Qwertiy способ не добавлялся до того, как я его добавил на SO